# Search & Replace all occurences of a word in the mysql > CLI

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface, aws-cloud9

I am using the mysql CLI in AWS Cloud9.

I have a SQL query :

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE employees( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, last_name TEXT NOT NULL, first_name TEXT NOT NULL, middle_name TEXT NOT NULL, age INT NOT NULL, current_status TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "employed");
```

this gives me an error trying to run the query however.
`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

I want to change all occurences of `TEXT` to be `VARCHAR(20)`.  What is the command to highlight all occurenes of the word, and then  replacing them with another word?

Answer (score 0):

If the TABLE employees already exists you can change the column type from TEXT to VARCHAR(20) with an ALTER statement.

`mysql>ALTER TABLE employees MODIFY last_name varchar(20) NOT NULL, MODIFY first_name varchar(20) NOT NULL, MODIFY middle_name varchar(20) NOT NULL, MODIFY current_status varchar(20) NOT NULL;`

If the employees table does not exist you can create it with...

`mysql>CREATE TABLE employees(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, last_name varchar(20) NOT NULL, first_name varchar(20) NOT NULL, middle_name varchar(20) NOT NULL, age INT NOT NULL, current_status varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT "employed", primary key (id));`

Then you can review your changes.

```
mysql> describe employees;

+----------------+-------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default  | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL     | auto_increment |
| last_name      | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| first_name     | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| middle_name    | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| age            | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| current_status | varchar(20) | NO   |     | employed |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
```